# Tic Tac Toe in Python with Minmax

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minmax

As a project I was implementing MinMax Tic Tac Toe AI in Python. I further implemented Alpha - Beta Pruning and came up with this huge code.

Code:-

```
class TicTacToe:
    game_state = [[' ',' ',' '],
                [' ',' ',' '],
                [' ',' ',' ']]
    players = ['X','O']
    def __init__(self,player_idx=0):
        if(player_idx>1 or player_idx<0):
        raise Exception("player index can only be 0 or 1")
        self.current_player=player_idx
    def check_current_state(self):
        # Check if draw
        draw_flag = 0
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.game_state[i][j] is ' ':
                    draw_flag = 1
        if draw_flag is 0:
            return None, "Draw"
        
        # Check horizontals
        if (self.game_state[0][0] == self.game_state[0][1] and self.game_state[0][1] == self.game_state[0][2] and self.game_state[0][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][0], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[1][0] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[1][2] and self.game_state[1][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[1][0], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[2][0] == self.game_state[2][1] and self.game_state[2][1] == self.game_state[2][2] and self.game_state[2][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[2][0], "Done"
        
        # Check verticals
        if (self.game_state[0][0] == self.game_state[1][0] and self.game_state[1][0] == self.game_state[2][0] and self.game_state[0][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][0], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[0][1] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[2][1] and self.game_state[0][1] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][1], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[0][2] == self.game_state[1][2] and self.game_state[1][2] == self.game_state[2][2] and self.game_state[0][2] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][2], "Done"
        
        # Check diagonals
        if (self.game_state[0][0] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[2][2] and self.game_state[0][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[1][1], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[2][0] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[0][2] and self.game_state[2][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[1][1], "Done"
        
        return None, "Not Done"
    def evaluate(self):
        a,b=self.check_current_state()
        if(a != None and b == "Done" and a == 'X'):
        return 1
        elif(a != None and b == "Done" and a == 'O'):
        return -1
        elif(a == None and b == "Draw"):
        return 0
        else:
        return 6
    def MiniMax(self,depth,isMax):
        score=self.evaluate()
        if(score==1):
        return score;
        if(score==-1):
        return score;
        if(score==0):
        return score
        if(isMax==True):
        best=-100
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
            if(self.game_state[i][j]==' '):
                self.game_state[i][j]='X'
                best=max(best,self.MiniMax(depth+1,False))
                self.game_state[i][j]=' '
        return best
        elif(isMax==False):
        best=100
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
            if(self.game_state[i][j]==' '):
                self.game_state[i][j]='O'
                best=min(best,self.MiniMax(depth+1,True))
                self.game_state[i][j]=' '
        return best
    
    def best_move(self):
        best=-100
        r=-1
        c=-1
        for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if(self.game_state[i][j]==' '):
            self.game_state[i][j]='X'
            move = self.MiniMax(0, False)
            self.game_state[i][j]=' '
            if(move>best):
                r=i
                c=j
                best=move
        return r,c
    def play_move(self, block_num):
        if self.game_state[int((block_num-1)/3)][(block_num-1)%3] is ' ' and self.current_player==1:
            self.game_state[int((block_num-1)/3)][(block_num-1)%3] = self.players[self.current_player]
            self.current_player=1-self.current_player
        elif self.current_player==0:
            i,j=self.best_move()
            self.game_state[i][j] = self.players[self.current_player]
            self.current_player=1-self.current_player
        elif self.game_state[int((block_num-1)/3)][(block_num-1)%3] != ' ' and self.current_player==1:
            block_num = int(input("Block is not empty, ya blockhead! Choose again: "))
            self.play_move(block_num)
        
    def print_board(self):
        print('----------------')
        print('| ' + str(self.game_state[0][0]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[0][1]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[0][2]) + ' |')
        print('----------------')
        print('| ' + str(self.game_state[1][0]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[1][1]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[1][2]) + ' |')
        print('----------------')
        print('| ' + str(self.game_state[2][0]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[2][1]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[2][2]) + ' |')
        print('----------------')

    def play(self):
        current_state = "Not Done"
        print("New Game!")
        self.print_board()
        winner = None
        while current_state == "Not Done":
            if(self.current_player==1):
            block_choice = int(input(str(self.players[self.current_player]) + "s Turn! Choose where to place (1 to 9): "))
            self.play_move(block_choice)
            elif(self.current_player==0):
            self.play_move(1)
            self.print_board()
            winner, current_state = self.check_current_state()
            if winner is not None:
                print(str(winner) + " won!")

            if current_state is "Draw":
                print("Draw!")

    game=TicTacToe()
    game.play()
```

I don't know why but this code is giving Issues.

Please help me out.

Comment: Hi Dhaval, welcome to StackOverflow! When you say "this code is giving issues", you need to specify _what_ issues. Please take the [tour] and go through [ask] for information on how to ask good questions that will get helpful answers and be useful to other users of SO in the future.

Comment: Also, please fix your code indentation. I tried giving it a shot but it's too ambiguous for me to figure out what your intended indentation was.

Comment: This question isn't focused. Debugging is an important skill which doesn't consist of dumping your whole code on Stack Overflow. You should have done enough debugging on your own to at least narrow it down to a specific problem and then to ask a question about that. Please read about the importance of providing a [mcve]. This code dump is far from minimal.

Comment: I am reaaly sorry for this.. i am very new on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had indentation problems I have fixed it for you:

```
class TicTacToe:
    game_state = [[' ',' ',' '],
                [' ',' ',' '],
                [' ',' ',' ']]
    players = ['X','O']
    def __init__(self,player_idx=0):
        if(player_idx>1 or player_idx<0):
            raise Exception("player index can only be 0 or 1")
        self.current_player=player_idx
    def check_current_state(self):
        # Check if draw
        draw_flag = 0
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.game_state[i][j] is ' ':
                    draw_flag = 1
        if draw_flag is 0:
            return None, "Draw"
        
        # Check horizontals
        if (self.game_state[0][0] == self.game_state[0][1] and self.game_state[0][1] == self.game_state[0][2] and self.game_state[0][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][0], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[1][0] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[1][2] and self.game_state[1][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[1][0], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[2][0] == self.game_state[2][1] and self.game_state[2][1] == self.game_state[2][2] and self.game_state[2][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[2][0], "Done"
        
        # Check verticals
        if (self.game_state[0][0] == self.game_state[1][0] and self.game_state[1][0] == self.game_state[2][0] and self.game_state[0][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][0], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[0][1] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[2][1] and self.game_state[0][1] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][1], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[0][2] == self.game_state[1][2] and self.game_state[1][2] == self.game_state[2][2] and self.game_state[0][2] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[0][2], "Done"
        
        # Check diagonals
        if (self.game_state[0][0] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[2][2] and self.game_state[0][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[1][1], "Done"
        if (self.game_state[2][0] == self.game_state[1][1] and self.game_state[1][1] == self.game_state[0][2] and self.game_state[2][0] is not ' '):
            return self.game_state[1][1], "Done"
        
        return None, "Not Done"
    def evaluate(self):
        a,b=self.check_current_state()
        if(a != None and b == "Done" and a == 'X'):
            return 1
        elif(a != None and b == "Done" and a == 'O'):
            return -1
        elif(a == None and b == "Draw"):
            return 0
        else:
            return 6
    def MiniMax(self,depth,isMax):
        score=self.evaluate()
        if(score==1):
            return score;
        if(score==-1):
            return score;
        if(score==0):
            return score
        if(isMax==True):
            best=-100
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    if(self.game_state[i][j]==' '):
                        self.game_state[i][j]='X'
                        best=max(best,self.MiniMax(depth+1,False))
                        self.game_state[i][j]=' '
            return best
        elif(isMax==False):
            best=100
            for i in range(3):
                for j in range(3):
                    if(self.game_state[i][j]==' '):
                        self.game_state[i][j]='O'
                        best=min(best,self.MiniMax(depth+1,True))
                        self.game_state[i][j]=' '
            return best
    
    def best_move(self):
        best=-100
        r=-1
        c=-1
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if(self.game_state[i][j]==' '):
                    self.game_state[i][j]='X'
                    move = self.MiniMax(0, False)
                    self.game_state[i][j]=' '
                    if(move>best):
                        r=i
                        c=j
                        best=move
        return r,c
    def play_move(self, block_num):
        if self.game_state[int((block_num-1)/3)][(block_num-1)%3] is ' ' and self.current_player==1:
            self.game_state[int((block_num-1)/3)][(block_num-1)%3] = self.players[self.current_player]
            self.current_player=1-self.current_player
        elif self.current_player==0:
            i,j=self.best_move()
            self.game_state[i][j] = self.players[self.current_player]
            self.current_player=1-self.current_player
        elif self.game_state[int((block_num-1)/3)][(block_num-1)%3] != ' ' and self.current_player==1:
            block_num = int(input("Block is not empty, ya blockhead! Choose again: "))
            self.play_move(block_num)
        
    def print_board(self):
        print('----------------')
        print('| ' + str(self.game_state[0][0]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[0][1]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[0][2]) + ' |')
        print('----------------')
        print('| ' + str(self.game_state[1][0]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[1][1]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[1][2]) + ' |')
        print('----------------')
        print('| ' + str(self.game_state[2][0]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[2][1]) + ' || ' + str(self.game_state[2][2]) + ' |')
        print('----------------')

    def play(self):
        current_state = "Not Done"
        print("New Game!")
        self.print_board()
        winner = None
        while current_state == "Not Done":
            if(self.current_player==1):
                block_choice = int(input(str(self.players[self.current_player]) + "s Turn! Choose where to place (1 to 9): "))
                self.play_move(block_choice)
            elif(self.current_player==0):
                self.play_move(1)
                self.print_board()
            winner, current_state = self.check_current_state()
            if winner is not None:
                print(str(winner) + " won!")

            if current_state is "Draw":
                print("Draw!")

game=TicTacToe()
game.play()
```

Comment: @DhavalBothra in your post you mentionned your code had issues I think due to the indentation mistakes. your code is slow at the beggining; try to fix it, other than that it's good.

Comment: yes min max is like brute force so I am applying alpha beta puring which makes computer see less cases other then that python has slow performance in recurrsion.